# How to properly express "to dwell on something" in German

Tags: meaning, translation, english-to-german, german-to-english

Quick question: What is the best way to express, "to dwell on something" in German, in the sense of, to worry/think too much about something. Let's consider the following sentences:

1. You should not dwell too much on your past mistakes.
2. You shouldn't dwell on the past.

Most dictionaries suggest, "bei etwas verweilen". Thus, maybe a proper translation would be

1'. Du solltest nicht bei deinen vorigen Fehler verweilen.

2'. Du solltest in der Vergangenheit nicht verweilen. (Here, it seems "in" instead of "bei" is used)

However, I see very few matches on the internet for "bei einem Fehler verweilen" and similar phrases. I see "auf einen Fehler verweilen", "in dem Fehler verweilen", and even "an einem Fehler verweilen". In fact, I don't see many examples at all.

Is this a correct way of expressing this idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While the word *[verweilen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verweilen)* means to pause and to spend some time dealing with something, there are better alternatives for *to dwell on something*.

> Sich mit etwas [aufhalten](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aufhalten)

includes wasting time and being prevented from progressing.

**Example:** Du solltest dich nicht zu lange mit der Vergangenheit aufhalten.

A second option would be

> auf etwas [herumreiten](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/herumreiten)

This expresses the overly long or overly intense preoccupation with something.

**Example:** Du solltest nicht auf begangenen Fehlern herumreiten.

---

Während das Wort [verweilen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verweilen) bedeutet, innezuhalten und sich eine Zeit lang mit etwas zu beschäftigen, gibt es für *to dwell on something* bessere Alternativen.

> Sich mit etwas [aufhalten](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aufhalten)

beinhaltet die Wertung, Zeit zu verschwenden und daran gehindert werden, weiterzukommen.

**Beispiel:** Du solltest dich nicht zu lange mit der Vergangenheit aufhalten.

Eine zweite Möglichkeit wäre

> auf etwas [herumreiten](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/herumreiten)

Damit wird die übermäßig lange oder übermäßig intensive Beschäftigung mit etwas ausgedrückt.

**Beispiel:** Du solltest nicht auf begangenen Fehlern herumreiten.

Comment: Thanks! So, would

Du solltest nicht auf der Vergangenheit herumreiten

be appropriate?

Comment: Yes. Usually *herumreiten* is used in respect of mistakes. But you can also use it when someone is always talking about the past instead of the present.

Comment: *Du solltest nicht auf X herumreiten* is typically not said to someone lamenting about his own mistakes but rather to someone who critisizes mistakes made by the speaker or a third person.

Answer (score 0):

The most used way to express this in German would be

> Zerbrich Dir nicht (zuviel) den Kopf darüber

(literally: don't break your head (too much) about it).

If it is about something in the past (and therefore cannot be changed any more), a typical proverb would be:

> Man soll sich nicht über vergossene Milch ärgern

(Don’t cry over spilt milk )

Comment: Isn't that proverb quite old-fashioned? Or is it regional? I've never heard it in native spoken language.

Comment: @Cacambo I have heard (and read) it a few times in my life, never so often that I could name a time or frequency, so the last time I heard it might be 1 or 2 decades ago, and maybe I always heard it from people older than me (1968)